# Android Studio 2.2 Preview 7: Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated the Android Studio version 2.7, When I created a new project today, it is displaying the error

**Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to**

[image: gradle]
[image: gradle2]

Comment: Can u tell me the Gradle version and Android plugin version which you can see that in project structure window?

Comment: @Raghavendra as u  see in picture  , thankies

Answer (score 0):

Just click `Fix build vesrion and sync project`.

Android Studio would automatically change plugin version to the newest one and rebuild your project.

This problem was propably caused by using Canary Version of Android Studio which with every version needs newer gradle plugin version. Already you have `2.2.0-alpha7`, `needs at least 2.2.0-beta3`

Hope it help